# Wrong text format phpExcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I'm creating a php script that queries a remote SQL database and export results on an excel via PHPExcel.
In my database I have a column of varchars called "syllabus" with this values [image].
If I create a simple table on HTML the text is correct[image]
But if I export to excel it return me this:[image]
The column is formatted as text and if I insert data manually it works without problem.
This is the script:`errno) die($mysqli->error);

```
require_once '/home/ecdlmalignani/ecdl.malignani.org/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$phpExcel = new PHPExcel;

// Load an existing spreadsheet
$phpExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('/home/ecdlmalignani/ecdl.malignani.org/template.xlsx');

if(isset($_GET['sessione']))
{
    $sql  = "SELECT skill_card.`ID_skillCard`, utenti.cognome, utenti.nome, DATE_FORMAT(utenti.data_nascita, '%d/%m/%Y') AS date, moduli.descrizione_modulo, moduli.syllabus\n"
            . "FROM `skill_card` INNER JOIN utenti ON skill_card.`cod_fiscale` = utenti.cod_fiscale\n"
            . "INNER JOIN esami ON esami.skill_card = skill_card.`ID_skillCard`\n"
            . "INNER JOIN moduli ON moduli.ID_modulo = esami.ID_modulo\n"
            . "WHERE esami.ID_sessione=".$_GET['sessione']." AND esami.pagato = 'SI' AND esami.stato = 'ISCRITTO'";
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row_increment = 0;
    while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
        for($column_increment = 0; $column_increment < 5; $column_increment++)
        {
            $cell = chr(65+$column_increment) . chr(50+$row_increment);
            $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell, $row[$column_increment]);
        }
        $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.chr(50+$row_increment), $row['syllabus']);
        $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.chr(50+$row_increment),'it');
        $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.chr(50+$row_increment),'ATLAS');
        $row_increment++;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="iscrizioni.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: So make that column a text column in Excel.

Comment: I have already did it, i resolved adding "\0" at the end of the row

Comment: Use `setCellValueExplicit()` if you don't want PHPExcel to try and determine the datatype for you, but want to ensure that it is set as a string value